# Native crash using HotRestart

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to use Xamarin HotRestart with Visual Studio 2019 16.9.0 Preview 2.
The target device is an iPhone 7 Plus running iOS 14.3
I'm using Xamarin Forms 4.8.0.1687.

I've already removed the Splash Screen from info.plist, but this does not solve the problem.

Here is the stack trace:

```
=================================================================
Got a segv while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

    Native Crash Reporting


=================================================================


=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================

    0x100c28120 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_dump_native_crash_info

    0x100c2ba60 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_sigsegv_signal_handler_debug
    0x1c8b96d90 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : <redacted>

    0x100c1ecbc - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_handle_native_crash

    0x100dd2e90 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_transform_method

    0x100de7758 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_interp_transform_method

    0x100dc6ef4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_interp_get_imethod
    0x100de4ef0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : generate_code

    0x100dca354 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_exec_method_full

    0x100dcd03c - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_exec_method_full

    0x100dc8028 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_runtime_invoke

    0x100cdeaf4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_try_invoke

    0x100c2ed3c - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_runtime_invoke

    0x100c39e54 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : suspend_current

    0x100c405bc - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : process_event

    0x100c37268 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : debugger_agent_breakpoint_from_context

    0x100be71d4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : sdb_breakpoint_trampoline

    0x100c3a928 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_invoke_method

    0x100dd3044 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_debugger_tramp

    0x100dd1390 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_exec_method_full

    0x100c386d4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : process_breakpoint_events
    0x100c52390 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_de_process_breakpoint

    0x100dc8028 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_runtime_invoke

    0x100ce3974 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_try_invoke_array

    0x100c2ed3c - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_runtime_invoke
    0x100cdd2c0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke_checked

    0x100c8b9c4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : ves_icall_InternalInvoke

    0x100dd4a74 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall
    0x100dd3188 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall_wrapper

    0x100dc8028 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_runtime_invoke

    0x100c9bb68 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : ves_icall_InternalInvoke_raw

    0x100bdbbc8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : main
    0x1800ca568 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x100dc6f00):
    0x100ce2564 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_exec_main_checked

    0x100c138f4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_exec

    0x100dc9c04 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_exec_method_full

fa 97 f6 03 00 aa 14 00 00 f9 17 58 00 f9  4............X..
0x100dc6f00  08 13 40 79 08 68 

0x100dc6f20  e8 17 9f 
    0x100dc5afc - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : xamarin_main

1a 09 
0f 40 b9 08 59 16 53  ..@y.h....@..Y.S
0x100dc6f10  08 6c 00 b9 08 0f 40 b9 08 15 10 12 1f 41 41 71  .l....@......AAq
b9 
90 
40 39 29 79 1e 12 28 05 
0x100dc6ef0  34 db 
00 
08 
    0x100c2ed3c - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_runtime_invoke
    0x100cdd2c0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/27648452-5A13-43A8-9E9F-B8EF1544DAF4/GeoFleet.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke_checked

      at Xamarin.HotReload.Forms.FormsAgent:InitializeAgentAsync <0x001d0>
      at <InitAgents>d__28:MoveNext <0x0023a>
      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder:Start <0x00052>
      at Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadAgent:InitAgents <0x0003e>
      at Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadAgent:.ctor <0x00096>
      at Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadAgent:GetInstance <0x0001e>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_direct_HotReloadAgent_uint_bool_string <0x00064>
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at GeoFleet.iOS.Application:Main <0x00004>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_direct_void_string[] <0x0008c>
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo:InternalInvoke <0x00030>
      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo:Invoke <0x000fc>
      at System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke <0x0001a>
      at Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS.Applications:Main <0x00254>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_direct_void_string[] <0x00092>
=================================================================

08 2a  ......@9)y..(..*

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at Xamarin.HotReload.Forms.VisualTreeService.DiagnosticVisualTreeService:Initialize <0x00140>
      at Xamarin.HotReload.Forms.FormsAgent:SetupAgent <0x000a8>

The app has been terminated.
```

Comment: Xamarin Hot Restart  is still in preview . So you could post the issue to github https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13179

Comment: By the way , you could build your project on VS latest stable version .